# pass data from sql to gridview using mfc

Tags: c++, sql, mfc

I have A MFC application. I tried to add data to gridview from sql procedure. When I call the procedure there is no data shown in grid view, but sql server profiler executed the procedure and returned data. 
Again, when I remove one specific column from procedure the data returned and shown in grid but the column that I removed is very important to be shown in gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast the field as NVARCHAR OR any Data Type Using Less Than Number Of Character